# The models objects have been created in Django admin, but after I added three pieces of information, they are not displayed in 127.0.0.1/admin/

Tags: python

The models objects have been created in Django admin.py, but after I added three pieces of information, they are not displayed in http://127.0.0.1:5757/admin/polls/userprofile/. How can I solve this problem?

[圖一 : admin.py - Is empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXeTS.png) ，
[圖二 : pgAdmin database - There are three pieces of information into the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8asZg.png)

```
- admin.py - 

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import *

admin.site.register(UserProfile) 

or 

(Additional supplements:)

# class UserProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
#   list_display = ('user', 'description', 'city', 'website', 'phone', 'image')
#   list_filter = ('phone',)
#   search_fields = ('phone',)
#   fields = ('user', 'description', 'city', 'website',
#             'phone', )  
#   ordering = ('-city',)
  # list_display = ('user', 'description', 'city', 'phone', 'website', 'image')
  # list_display_link = ('description', 'city', 'phone', 'website', 'image')
  # search_fields = ('city',)

  # def user_info(self, obj):
  #   return obj.description
  # user_info.short_description = '高香資訊'

  # def get_queryset(self, request):
  #   queryset = super(UserProfileAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
  #   queryset = queryset.order_by('-phone')
  #   return queryset

  # class Meta:
  #   modle = UserProfile

# admin.site.register(UserProfile, UserProfileAdmin)
```

```
- models.py -
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class UserProfileManager(models.Manager):
  def get_queryset(self):
    return super(UserProfileManager, self).get_queryset().filter(city='London')

class UserProfile(models.Model):
  user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='', primary_key=True,)
  description = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
  city = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
  website = models.URLField(default='')
  phone = models.IntegerField(default=0)
  image = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_image', blank=True)

  london = UserProfileManager()

  def __str__(self):
    return self.user.username
```

```
- urls.py -
path('profile/', views.polls_profile, name='polls_profile'),  # http://127.0.0.1:8000/posts/list
```

```
- settings.py -

INSTALLED_APPS = [
  'django.contrib.admin',
  'django.contrib.auth',
  'django.contrib.contenttypes',
  'django.contrib.sessions',
  'django.contrib.messages',
  'django.contrib.staticfiles',
  # 套版
  # 'crispy_forms',

  # app
  'polls',
  'accounts',
  'shops',
]
```

If there is incomplete information, please tell me again, thank you !!!!!!

```
ps: I deleted all the passwords

"""
Django settings for mysite project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.2.4.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/
"""
import os
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
# BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
# BASE_DIR = "C:\Users\wleej\PycharmProjects\mysite"

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-7r4mj*$^bv(zj@#+$d42&k$'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
  'django.contrib.admin',
  'django.contrib.auth',
  'django.contrib.contenttypes',
  'django.contrib.sessions',
  'django.contrib.messages',
  'django.contrib.staticfiles',
  # 套版
  # 'crispy_forms',

  # app
  'polls',
  'accounts',
  'shops',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
  'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
  'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
  'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
  'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
  'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
  'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
  'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
  {
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
      'context_processors': [
        'django.template.context_processors.debug',
        'django.template.context_processors.request',
        'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
        'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
      ],
    },
  },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
  'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME': 'restA_db',
    'USER': 'postgres',
    'PASSWORD': '',
    'HOST': 'localhost',
    'PORT': '5432',
  }
}

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
  {
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
  },
  {
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
  },
  {
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
  },
  {
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
  },
]

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'zh-Hant'

TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Taipei'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
# STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static_cdn")
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
  # https://code.ziqiangxuetang.com/django/django-static-files.html
  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
  '/var/www/static/',  
]

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/dist/media_cdn")
# http://127.0.0.1:5757/media/profile_image/Phone_2.jpg

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

# Redirect to home URL after login (Default redirects to /accounts/profile/)
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/polls/'
LOGIN_URL = '/accounts/login/'
# LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = '/accounts/logout/'

# crispy_forms
# CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'

# STMP Configuration
if DEBUG:
  EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = '587'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = '@gmail.com'  # 寄件者帳號
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = ''  # 寄件者password
```

Comment: Have you add your app to `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py`?

Comment: 我沒有缺少這些基本項目，數據資料庫裏面有但是/admin/畫面就是沒有呈現，我貼上相關資訊您看看。
請查收 感謝您
I do not lack these basic items. There are in the data database but the /admin/ screen is not displayed. I will post relevant information for you to see.
Please check thank you